# disabling send button

Tags: javascript, html

I just a got a requirement to disable the send button in the form until the users enter his data.Can any one guide me?
thanks

Comment: Please show some code. I'm also retagging, as this has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: That's not going to work with PHP (since it's a server-side language). You'll need to use JavaScript for this (client-side). I'd recommend jQuery, personally, but other libraries are more than capable of providing this functionality.

Comment: Recommendation: Modify the title and take out "PHP" from it...

Comment: Other recommendation: search about "Javascript form validation" (or even better "JQuery form validation").

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should mark the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have the button initially disabled by having such HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" disabled="disabled" value="Send" />
```

Then in the `blur` event of your form elements check if user entered all required data and when this happens, enable the button using such code:

```
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would code it for you, but I'm in a hurry, and you do have to learn how to search for yourself, so here's a hint:

`addEventListener()`, and you can check the length of the data within an input by calling `document.body.getElementById('yourInput').length`, and then you can change the `button.disabled` property to either true (make the default value `false` in the source code). All you need to do for yourself is find out how to use `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

form action="javascript:aNameForAnAjaxSendPostFunction"

function aNameForAnAjaxSendPostFunction()
{
   if ((document.getElementById('your field').value.strlen>0))
  {
      << SEND REQUEST >>
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing what you want using JQuery:
(this works if you have only input texts)

HTML:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
<input type='text' name='name' />   
<input type='text' name='phone' />
<input type='text' name='email' />
<button type='submit' disabled='disabled'>Send</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
     $("input").change(function() {
          if($("input[value='']").length == 0) {
               $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
          } else {
               //disable again if a field is cleared
               $("button").attr("disabled",true); 
               alert("Please fill all fields");
               $("input[value='']").eq(0).focus();
          }
     });
});
```